# Godot imported texture becomes black at some distance until editor's restart

Tags: godot

Godot 3.4.

I have some model with shader. I am using texture there. When I place images into project's folder they appears in editor file system window. Then I drag one from there and drop to shader parameters window in texture slot.

It displays, but if I move camera closer it disappears (becomes black). Only after I restart the editor it display good.

Also, if I select the image in file system window, and then go to import tab and press reimport the editor's interface at all totally freezes, but the program itself works - if I move cursor around the window it will be changed; if I press windows close button it seems that the save before exit window appears and I can press "enter" to confirm saving and after that editor closing

[image]

P.S.: in the gif above texture used in a bit complicated masked way, but the problem appears always, even for just simple texture.

Comment: From the animation I'm thinking it is something to do with screen space reflections. I have also seen some people report that models get imported more reflective that they should be, so they had to tweak roughness or metalic of the material. However, that does not explain why it would result in a freeze. Well, unless the model is much heavier than it seems. Consider to report a bug at https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues

Comment: @Theraot, the problem with darkness disappears only after editor restart without tweaking any parameters such a roughness or metallic. And, perhaps important thing You could missed is that texture is visible at the distance where camera was when it (texture) was uploaded. If I come closer (short the distance) it starts to disappear, if far (from "upload" distance)- nothing changes (texture is visible).